# How do I get a function to be compiled at address 04 with GPLINK? (For PIC16)

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, sdcc

I have a function which is meant to catch **all** the interrupt calls that will happen, But I cannot get any function to start at address 04.

Note: I dont want to use functions that are specific to interrupt types, I dont want the overhead they produce in the code.

I have tried the following codes with SDCC, maybe not quite related but I will keep them here just in case.

```
__code __at (4) void handler() {
```

And

```
void __at (4) handler() {
```

With no luck, the manual does not explain any further also.

Comment: Added the “micocontroller” tag, I hope someone can help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a long time after the original question, but I am searching for the same answer and found this helpful info, confirmed working on SDCC 3.3.0:
(Source: http://www.mail-archive.com/sdcc-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00411.html)

To cause a function to be linked a a fixed, known address, you can surround the function with two other functions:  See example below.  NOTE: all the _ are double _ _ characters!
(You can also define the macros as in the above example, if you intend to use this multiple times throughout your code.

REPLACE #### with your function's desired address below:

test.c

```
void begin_absolute_code(void) __naked
{
    __asm
          .area ABSCODE (ABS,CODE)
          .org 0x####        // YOUR FUNCTION'S DESIRED ADDRESS HERE.
    __endasm;
}

void your_function(...)
{
     // Do stuff here. This code will be placed at the specified address.
}

void end_absolute_code(void) __naked
{
    __asm
        .area CSEG (REL,CODE)
    __endasm;
}

void other_functions_here(...)
    // These functions will return to relative positions determined by the linker.
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes, it is quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The location of a function is up to the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have edited the post accordingly.
But unfortunately this is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the function to start at address 4, you want the compiler to generate a jump at that location to your isr function.

A quick look at the SDCC documentation gives this structure:

```
void isr(void) interrupt n { /* your code goes here */ }
```

Where 'n' vector slot where you want the goto instruction.

Other compilers will have similar features, you need to check the compiler documentation for the exact incantation.

For example, using HiTech C:

```
void interrupt isr(void) { /* code */ }
```

Comment: I do want the function to start at address 4, just like I used to do with CC5X.
This answer does not solve my issue in any way.

Comment: @Mario: In C this answers your question. There are two issues with your response: 1. Putting the function directly at location 4 saves a single instruction. Do you really need that extra cycle and/or extra word? 2. The "overhead" of telling the compiler that your interrupt routine is an interrupt routine lets the compiler handle saving context & generate appropriate function prolog/epilog. If you need to optimise that, write in assembler and tell the assembler and linker what you want. In that case you should also know enough about what you are doing to not ask questions like this.

Comment: I know what I am doing and if I ask something it is because I need to do it. If you don’t know how to do it I understand, but at least don’t tell me that I want to do something different than what I asked. I would not have asked that otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in a mailing list.

Compile using `sdcc --codeseg SEGNAME -c file.c`
And link doing this `sdcc -Wl -bSEGNAME=0x7ff0 ...`